# Merge audio and resize video in the same ffmpeg command

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I have these two instructions in ffmpeg and I would like to know if I can use a single command for both with ffmpeg:

```
$w=1280
$h=720
ffmpeg -i $1 -vf scale=$w:$h -preset slow -crf 18 output_00.mp4
ffmpeg -i output_00.mp4 -i music.mp3 -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -shortest output_01.mp4
```

Thank you very much for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command suppose to work:

```
ffmpeg -i output_00.mp4 -i music.mp3 -vf scale=$w:$h -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -acodec copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -shortest output_01.mp4
```

---

- `-vf scale=$w:$h` applies video scale filter.
- `-vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 18` sets video codec and encoding parameters.
- `-acodec copy` - copy the audio without re-encoding.
- `-map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0` maps the first video stream of `output_00.mp4` and the first audio stream from `music.mp3` to the output.